# Can you configure Intellij IDEA to get back to where you started when erasing characters in incremental search?

Tags: intellij-idea, incremental-search

In Intellij IDEA, if you press **ctrl + F**, and start typing characters, you get incremental search that jumps to the first hit for each additional character entered. However, if you have entered a few characters already, and start erasing them one by one, you don’t jump back to the previous hits. Instead you stay at the current hit.

In Xemacs on the other hand, as you erase character by character in the incremental search (**ctrl + S**), you jump back to previous hits. When you have erased all the characters you entered, you are back to where you started.

Is there a way to configure Intellij IDEA to behave in the same way, i.e. if you have erased all the characters entered in the incremental search, you end up back where you started the search?

I am using Intellij IDEA 7.0.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible at the moment. Please Watch/Vote [IDEA-26887](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-26887).